# data-live-search-style data attribute is not working in bootstrap select js

Tags: html, bootstrap-select

I have used `bootstrap-select.min.js` to search in dropdown. But it gives wrong result. My html code looks like below :

```
<select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="4444">4444</option>
    <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
    <option value="Elite">Elite</option>
    <option value="Interp">Interp</option>
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
```

When I write `te` than it show `Elite, Interp and test` instead of `test`.

If I write `te` than it show only `test`. SO what should I have to change in my code?

Comment: You should change nothing. Your markups work exactly what you're expecting. Perhaps, you should check dependent CSS, JS.

Comment: @BobDust I need to show first `test` because I have written `te`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code snippet shows that your code is working:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="4444">4444</option>
  <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
  <option value="Elite">Elite</option>
  <option value="Interp">Interp</option>
  <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think my bootstrap jQuery version was old that's why it won't work before. Now, its working Thank you so much.

Comment: My issue solved with, I overwrite my _bootstrap.min.css_ with given CDN and filter is working now.

Comment: congrats @SPnL :D

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="4444">4444</option>
    <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
    <option value="Elite">Elite</option>
    <option value="Interp">Interp</option>
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Try this, it works as you expected.

Comment: Please explain why this pice of code answers the question.

Comment: Thank you. Nice answer but please explain this so we can understand why try this piece of code as this is same as above

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My search-result for liveSearchStyle "startsWith" was always empty for each search-value. After a while I've figured out, that this was an mapping issue. This is how it worked for me:

```
<abp-select
    picker-options.bind="{ liveSearch: true, dropupAuto: false, noneSelectedText: '', liveSearchStyle: 'startsWith' }"
    collection.bind="items"
    selected-item.bind="selectedItem"
    data-mapping-structure.bind="{ option: 'standardDisplayText', content: 'standardDisplayText' }"
    object-key="key">
</abp-select>

export interface IItem {
    key: string;
    value: string;
    displayText: string;
}

public items: IItem[];
public selectedItem: IItem;

items = [
    { key: '121', value: 'hello', displayText: '121 - hello' },
    { key: '112', value: 'world', displayText: '112 - world' },
];

search for: "12"
result: "121 - hello"
```