# bootstrap-select Dropdown shows no entries

Tags: bootstrap-select

I use bootstrap-select in my form to display some suppliers, but it looks like this: [image]

My select looks like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Choose Supplier"> 
    <option data-tokens="Supplier 1">Supplier 1</option>
    <option data-tokens="Supplier 2">Supplier 2</option>
    <option data-tokens="Supplier 3">Supplier 3</option>
    <option data-tokens="add Supplier">Add Supplier</option>
</select>
```

The .css file is linked in the `head` tag and the .js is linked at the end of the site. What is the problem with this code? In the [examples](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) it looks the same but on my site it do not work. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in example using bootstrap-select.min.css 
that's why not show you like example.

Comment: I link to the css in the head tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">` and the JS file is linked at the end of the page.

Comment: it looks like on the picture in the question. there are already all necessary files linked.

Comment: can i see your website link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757224/data-live-search-style-data-attribute-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-select-js

Comment: i think your js files priority create problem. you can check js files change location.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  </head>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
      <p>This uses <a href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/">https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/</a></p>
      <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
        <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
        <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
        <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
      </select>
      <span class="help-inline">With <code>data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"</code>. Try searching for california</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</html>
```